# Removing the handle from this type of faucet/tap

Tags: plumbing, faucet, valve

I have this type of washing machine faucet/tap in my apartment. Any idea how to remove the handle? There isnt any screw on top(after removal of the sticker), by the side, or back of the handle.

Is there special tool to unlock the valve handle?

Photo updated
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a couple photos from different angles?  It's possible that the cover (where it says "*HOT*") pops/screws off, revealing a screw. Another common practice, is to have a set screw (usually in a small hole behind the handle).

Comment: Picture with the sticker off, please. Also, why are you only trying to remove the handle?

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if there is a nut just below the handle which the stem comes out of. If this is a laundry faucet or the type that projects from a wall there may be a connecting nut that allows the faucet to swivel into alignment with the supply pipe. Either way use a crescent (adjustable jaw) wrench or as @bib mentioned tape or a rag to protect the faucet from being marred.

Comment: There isnt any nuts on the stem, which is strange

Comment: Sometimes there's a set screw on the valve stem using a mini-hex screw.

Comment: Are you changing the washer? Or replacing the valve? If the washer needs replacing you may have to unscrew the faucet from the pipe that supplies the water. Then looking into the faucet you should have access to the washer. Also, look to see if the faucet body has a seam , however slight, which can be un- threaded.

Comment: @CalebC - Look at the picture, the entire front housing is a 'nut'. Grab the back part of the valve with a wrench and a rag (try to grab above the threads but still grab the 'arm' of it, or put the hose back on to protect it), and spin the front housing off with another wrench. If that's not how it works, I'd just put a new valve in.